# Why do I get error compiling Ruby 3.2 on CentOS 7?

Tags: c, ruby, linux, centos7

I try to build Ruby 3.2 using ruby-build plugin for rbenv but get some strange compilation error:

```
compiling bignum.c
In file included from vm_core.h:164:0,
                 from iseq.h:14,
                 from mini_builtin.c:3,
                 from miniinit.c:51:
thread_pthread.h:109:39: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘struct’
 RUBY_EXTERN RB_THREAD_LOCAL_SPECIFIER struct rb_execution_context_struct *ruby_current_ec;
                                       ^
In file included from iseq.h:14:0,
                 from mini_builtin.c:3,
                 from miniinit.c:51:
vm_core.h: In function ‘rb_current_execution_context’:
vm_core.h:1864:34: error: ‘ruby_current_ec’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     rb_execution_context_t *ec = ruby_current_ec;
                                  ^
vm_core.h:1864:34: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

Here is the full log: https://gist.github.com/tycooon/c077a1d99299469bd86131211c565ff7.

Ruby 3.1 builds without any problems on the same machine. What could be the problem?

Comment: try to reinstall/rebuild ruby 3.2

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem was centos7 being shipped with too old GCC. There was `devtoolset-7-gcc.x86_64` package available on the machine in my case, so I was able to install Ruby 3.2 using the following command:

```
CC=/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc rbenv install 3.2.0 -v
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This was a big help, thank you. I also found that I needed to update the `binutils` package so `ld` recognised the `--compress-debug-sections=zlib` flag.

Comment: ...and don't forget to install `rustc` to enable YJIT.

Answer (score 4):

As others have pointed out, the culprit is outdated version of GCC. To resolve the issue, follow the following steps to install and activate an newer version of GCC.

### Solution

1. **Enable a Software Repository with a Newer GCC Version:**

   ```bash
   sudo yum install centos-release-scl
   ```
2. **Install a Newer GCC Version:**

   ```bash
   sudo yum install devtoolset-9-gcc devtoolset-9-gcc-c++ devtoolset-9-binutils
   ```
3. **Activate the Newer GCC Version:**

   ```bash
   scl enable devtoolset-9 bash
   ```
4. **Confirm that the new version of GCC is activated:**

   ```bash
   gcc --version
   ```

   You'll see something like this:

   ```bash
   gcc (GCC) 9.3.1 20200408 (Red Hat 9.3.1-2)
   Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
   This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
   warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
   ```
5. **Make the dev tools selection permanent:**

   Place the following code in `/etc/profile` or `/etc/bashrc`:

   ```bash
   source scl_source enable devtoolset-9
   ```

   Then run the appropriate source command below:

   ```bash
   source /etc/profile
   source /etc/bashrc
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem with CentOS 7 and ruby 3.1.4 and @tycoon's solution provided the solution here too. For more completeness I'll add this:

```
# As root
yum install centos-release-scl-rh
yum install devtoolset-7-gcc-c++
# As deploying user
CC=/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc rbenv install 3.1.4 -v
```